# Can the value the $x/(f(x)^2)$ touch the real line of $(r/(f(r)^2),\infty)$, where $f(x)$ is power series and $r$ is radius of convergence of $f(x)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

In complex plane, $f(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ is a power series with positive coefficients, i.e. $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Suppose the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ is $r$ and $f(r)$ is convergent. It implies that $f(x)$ is convergent in the closed disc of $|x|\leq r$. Here is my problem:

When $|x|\leq r$, is it possible that the value of $\frac{x}{f(x)^2}$ is equal to a real number $R$ where $R>\frac{r}{f(r)^2}$?

P.S. the problem given above is produced during my studying of analyticity of a generating function, called $G$. $G$ is a composite function of $F(x/f(x)^2)$, where $F$ is analytic except the line of $[r/f(r)^2,\infty)$. Unfortunately, neither $F$ or $f$ is expressed by explicit functions. If I can prove the problem given above is false, then $G$ is analytic in the disc of $|x|<r$.

Thanks very much for your precious discussion.

Comment: So you are asking if $f(x)^2/x < f(r)^2/r$ is possible? Can you provide some background? Why do you think that it is possible (or not), and why would that be a useful result?

Comment: The background is that I am studying analyticity of a generating function $G$, which is a composite function of $F(x/(f(x)^2))$, where $F$ is analytic except the line of $[r/(f(r)^2),\infty)$. Unfortunately, neither $F$ or $f$ is expressed by explicit functions. If I can prove the problem given above is false, then $G$ is analytic in the disc of $|x|<r$.

Comment: I would suggest that you add that information to the question itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here is an example:
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
satisfies all conditions, the radius of convergence is $r=1$ and $f(1) = 1$.

$f$ has a closed form which can be determined by integrating the geometric series twice (or simply use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+z%5En%2F%28%28n%2B1%29*%28n%2B2%29%29%2C+n%3D0...infinity)):
$$
 f(z) = \frac{z + (1-z)\log(1-z)}{z^2} \, .
$$

For $x= 1/2$ is $f(x) = 2  - \log(4) \approx 0.61371$ and
$$
\frac{x}{f(x)^2} \approx 1.3275 > 1 = \frac{1}{f(1)^2} \, .
$$